# How to detect if webcomponentsjs polyfill is not supported?

Tags: html, browser, web-component, polyfills, html5-template

Is there a simple way to detect if the user's browser supports neither [Web Components](https://www.webcomponents.org/) nor the [webcomponentsjs polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No for different reasons:

- Web Components is a set a severral distinct features (Custom Elements, Shadow DOM, HTML template, HTML Imports), so some could be supported by one browser version while other not.
- Polyfills themselves are using JavaScript "advanced" features that are not necessarily implemented in the broser. For example, ShadyCSS is using Array.from() that is not implemented in Internet Explorer 11 and therefore needs another polyfill to work.

Therefore, depending on what you really need, use an ad-hoc [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) test, or `try` / `catch` test.